# swift return costum cell from storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have a static table view with 2 sections. Each section has two rows. The first row is a date picker cell (DVDatePickerTableViewCell). Now i put manually a textfield into the second cell.

In the view controller i load the cells with this code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID : NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {

        return cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as UITableViewCell
    }

    return cell
```

The Cell with the identifier "Cell" has the textfield in it. But when the table view is load, the first  cell works perfectly but the others are just empty cells. How can i return the cells with the "style", which i created in the storyboard?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to use static cells in your table view, make sure that "**Static cells**" is selected in your table view settings: [image: Table view settings]

In this case you don't need to implement `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, table view will handle cells loading and displaying automatically.
To link any outlets from Interface Builder to your code you don't even have to create custom classes for your cells, you can link your views from table view's cells in Interface Builder directly to your view controller:
[image: Linking outlet to controller]